# iothub-service-client support for android app

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have made a simple program on Raspberry Pi 3 with Python using Direct method on iothub and able to on/off LED using device explorer and getting response.

Now I want to make an Android app where I can on/off devices and get back a response, but I found out that there is still no support for iothub service client on Android,

[image]

Now I want recommendation for a better approach how to access Raspberry Pi with my Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Xamarin?  Our [.NET SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp) has support for Xamarin.  Android support is currently in development, please check back for release update.